# Fixed positioned div inside an absolute positioned div with a scrollbar: bug (?) in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

In the context of the development of a menu, I have a fixed position div (sort of popin that contains level 3 and more menu items) which is contained by an absolute positioned div (that contains level 2 items).

Sometimes the absolute div has a scrollbar and in this case this scrollbar appears above the fixed div on Google Chrome (this doesn't happen on FF and IE).

[Simplified jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ra65tepv/1/)

```css
.level-1 {
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.level-1-content {
  height: 200px;
}
.level-2 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="level-1">
  <div class="level-1-content"></div>
  <div class="level-2"></div>
</div>
```

This issue happens only when the fixed and/or the absolute div have a z-index.
In the jsfiddle simple example, the z-index are not required, but in the context of my menu, I need them.

Does anybody know a CSS solution in order to Chrome not to display this scrollbar above the child div in this context (I mean, with my constraints, i.e. the parent div is absolute and has a z-index and the child div is fixed) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use overflow-y: hidden; on the .level-1 class instead of overflow-y: auto; it seems fine in the fiddle you posted

Comment: Thanks Andy. Yes, if the parent is not scrollable it works. This is the solution I have implemented currently (when the blue div is displayed, i make the red one not scrollable. But I was wondering if there is a solution to keep the scrollbar and make it appear under the blue div.